# How to disable Magic Trackpad while typing?

Tags: keyboard, magic-trackpad

Is it possible to get the **external** Magic Trackpad disabled automatically while I'm typing?

I do get a lot of cursor movements/clicks when just touching the trackpad accidentally.

Comment: Magic Trackpad or Built-in Trackpad? I think you mean the last one.

Comment: It is for external Trackpad

Answer (score 1):

You could just goto your Bluetooth icon in the menu bar and disconnect it till you wish to start using it again, then goto said menu again and reconnect it.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the built-in trackpad, then you cannot disable it. But you can disable it if you connect an external mouse to your Mac.

To do, just open System Preferences > Accessibility (or Universal Access) > Mouse & Trackpad > tick on *Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present*

You're done.

Comment: It is for external Trackpad

Comment: yeah same here, want to do this for an external trackpad (magic trackpad)